# Google Analytics Funnel Regular Expression

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

I started to use GA recently. Now I'm creating funnels and my destination URL contains parameters that I want to replace with regular expressions.

Maybe it helps if I mention that I manage a mobile site that sells content for cell phones: ringtones, wallpapers, games, etc. These funnels will measure how many downloads each type of content have had.

This is the URL:
/buySuccess.jsp;jsessionid=72E8952C431483DA26AE7D33E3FE4EA7?f=133381&id=1543845&mt=VDEO

- "jsessionid" is the session id that changes with every session.
- "f" stands for frontend, which is fixed.
- "id" is the id of the purchased media.
- "mt" is for type of media, in this case a Video.

I believe if I replace "jsessionid" and "id", that will give me the total of downloads my videos have had.

So, using regular expressions, I've thought of this:
/buySuccess.jsp;jsessionid=**\w+**?f=133381&id=**\d+**&mt=VDEO

Any suggestions?

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Escape the question mark and replace the metacharacter **\w** with one that matches any alphanumeric string. Try this:

```
/buySuccess.jsp;jsessionid=[a-zA-Z0-9]+\?f=133381&id=\d+&mt=VDEO
```

Demo at http://regexr.com/38os9

Note: regexr forces you to escape forward slashes but the expression above will work fine.